# Java external Multithread

Tags: java, multithreading, progress-bar, external, splash-screen

I have the next Issue:

I am working with 2 classes in Java, both extend Thread, but I want those thrads to run in parallel.

This is my example: Animation class with thread for the progress bar animation and another class with thread to start the splash for the application (12 seconds), when I implement I see the Splash but I don't see the animation in the progress bar.

Main Class:

```
public class Run extends AppController {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Run.class.getName());
    public static Splash splash;

    public Run() {
    }

    /**
     * Application main class.
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // application splash form
        splash = new Splash(I18n.CUSTOMERS.getString("App.Title"),
                ViewHelpers.ICONS16 + "app.png",
                ViewHelpers.IMAGES + "splash.png");
        
        splash.setVisible(true);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                
                try {
                    controller = new Run();
                    controller.setSplash(splash);
                    Thread.sleep(12000);
                    
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                controller.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Splash Class:

```
public class Splash extends JFrame {

    //Title of Splash form.
    private final String title;
    //Icon path of Splash form.
    private final String iconPath;
    //Image path of Splash form.
    private final String imagePath;
    
    static JProgressBar progressBar;

    /**
     * Create splash form
     * 
     * @param title title of splash form for taskbar
     * @param iconPath icon path for taskbar
     * @param imagePath image path for splash form
     */
    public Splash(String title, String iconPath, String imagePath) {
        this.title = title;
        this.iconPath = iconPath;
        this.imagePath = imagePath;

        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        setTitle(title);
        setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(iconPath)).getImage());
        JLabel imgSplash = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(imagePath)));
        
        setResizable(false);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        
        progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
        progressBar.setValue(0);
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
        progressBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 20));
        
        getContentPane().add(imgSplash, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(progressBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

            animation fill = new animation();
            fill.start();
    }
    
    // function to increase progress 
    public class animation extends Thread implements Runnable{

        public void run(){
             int i = 0;
                try { 
                     for(i=1; i <= 100; i++){ 
                        // fill the menu bar 
                        progressBar.setValue(i); 
                        progressBar.repaint(); 
                        // delay the thread 
                        Time.time(250); 
                    } 
                } 
                catch (Exception e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
        }
    }
}
```

And finally Controller class:

```
public abstract class AppController {

    public static AppController controller;
    protected AppView appView;
    private Splash splash;

    public AppController() {
    }

    /** Start the application and show the application view. **/
    public void start() {

        if (splash != null) {
            splash.setVisible(false);
            splash.dispose();
        }

        //launch the next window
        appView = new AppView(I18n.CUSTOMERS.getString("App.Title"));
        appView.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void setSplash(Splash splash) {
        this.splash = splash;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nit : dont need to extend Thread and implmenet Runnable both in Animation class. Just 1 will do

Comment: The multi threading part seems correct. Can you have print statements inside the animation run() method to verify that it is getting triggered. Then you would know for sure that the problem is with the APIs you are calling and not with the threading

Comment: I comprobated with your suggest and this is my result:     ANIMATION RUN0
SPLASH RUN
ANIMATION RUN10
ANIMATION RUN20
ANIMATION RUN30
ANIMATION RUN40
ANIMATION RUN50
ANIMATION RUN60
ANIMATION RUN70
ANIMATION RUN80
ANIMATION RUN90
ANIMATION END
SPLASH END son in this case is problem of the api?

Comment: Yes. As you can clearly see, animation and progress bar both are getting called. So, perhaps the API is not right to view progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

Related of this I insert the prints for verify, my print is working now, but my progressbar is wrong. Why?

```
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            controller = new Run();
            
            try {
                controller.setSplash(splash);
                System.out.println("SPLASH RUN");
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            System.out.println("SPLASH END");
            controller.start();
        }
    });




// function to increase progress 
public class animation extends Thread implements Runnable{

    public void run(){
        int i = 0;
            while(i <= 100){
                if(i<100){
                    // fill the menu bar 
                    progressBar.setValue(i); 
                    progressBar.repaint(); 
                    // delay the thread 
                    Time.time(1000); 
                    System.out.println("ANIMATION RUN"+i);
                }
                else{
                    progressBar.setValue(100);
                    System.out.println("ANIMATION END");
                    break;
                }
            i=i+10;
            }
    } 
}
```

The result is the next:
ANIMATION RUN0,
SPLASH RUN
ANIMATION RUN10,
ANIMATION RUN20,
ANIMATION RUN30,
ANIMATION RUN40,
ANIMATION RUN50,
ANIMATION RUN60,
ANIMATION RUN70,
ANIMATION RUN80,
ANIMATION RUN90,
ANIMATION END
SPLASH END